# How can I concat strings that might be empty?

Tags: python, string, ansible

Currently I am trying to concat three strings in my Ansible playbook. Two of them can be unset (`None`/`null`) and I need them to be separated by underscores.

Here is an example: `type_mode="A"`, `level_mode=None`, and `what_to_run="C"` combines to `A_C`. If both where `None` it would just be `C`, if all where set it would be `A_B_C`.

My idea was to do this bit in Python:

```yaml
- name: "Set Name"
  set_fact:
    name: "{{ ('' if type_mode is None else type_mode + '_') + ('' if level_mode is None else level_mode + '_') + what_to_run }}"
```

But then I get this error:

```json
{
  "msg": "template error while templating string: Could not load \"None\": 'None'. String: {{ ('' if type_mode is None else type_mode + '_') + ('' if level_mode is None else level_mode + '_') + what_to_run }}. Could not load \"None\": 'None'",
  "_ansible_no_log": false
}
```

Do you have a idea how I can concat the (possible missing) values with an underscore separator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make a list out of your strings:

   ```yaml
   [type_mode, level_mode, what_to_run]
   ```
2. Exclude the blank parts with the help of the *[`select`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.select) filter*:

   ```yaml
   [type_mode, level_mode, what_to_run] | select
   ```
3. Join the remaining chunks

   ```yaml
   [type_mode, level_mode, what_to_run] | select | join('_')
   ```

Your `set_fact` task ends up being:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    name: "{{ [type_mode, level_mode, what_to_run] | select | join('_') }}"
```

---

If you also happen to have *undefined* variables, then you can add defaults to your strings:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    name: >-
      {{ 
        [
          type_mode | default(''), 
          level_mode | default(''), 
          what_to_run
        ] | select | join('_')
      }}
```

---

Given a playbook containing. only this task, running it with:

- Only `what_to_run`

  ```bash
  ansible-playbook play.ym --verbose \
    --extra-vars "what_to_run=foo" \
    --extra-vars "level_mode=" \
    --extra-vars "type_mode="
  ```

  would give

  ```yaml
  TASK [set_fact] *************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
    ansible_facts:
      var: foo
  ```
- Both `what_to_run` and `level_mode`

  ```bash
  ansible-playbook play.ym --verbose \
    --extra-vars "what_to_run=foo" \
    --extra-vars "level_mode=bar" \
    --extra-vars "type_mode="
  ```

  would give

  ```yaml
  TASK [set_fact] *************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
    ansible_facts:
      var: bar_foo
  ```
- The three variables filled in

  ```bash
  ansible-playbook play.ym --verbose \
    --extra-vars "what_to_run=foo" \
    --extra-vars "level_mode=bar" \
    --extra-vars "type_mode=baz"
  ```

  would give

  ```yaml
  TASK [set_fact] *************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
    ansible_facts:
      var: baz_bar_foo
  ```

Comment: This almost worked, I got a `'type_mode' is undefined.` error, but when I do it like this it works fine: `"{{ [type_mode | default(''), level_mode | default(''), what_to_run] | select | join('_') }}"` Thank you.

Comment: Yep, wasn't clear in your question that they could be undefined. [I started proposing a default](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77387816/1) but since your answer pointed at `null` / `None` and not undefined, I got that part out.